# Cakephp auto redirect to the intended page after logging in

Tags: php, cakephp

In Cakephp 2.0.6

I'm trying to make it so that user get redirected to the page he/she intended to go to prior to logging in so that after logging in it redirects to that page.

I'm using jQuery Mobile and Cakephp frameworks together.

```
public function login(){
        $this->layout = 'jquery-mobile';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
            }
        }
    }
```

Above function seems to be working ok sometimes but not all the time.

Is there something I could do to ensure it happens all the time?

Comment: What happens when not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After succesfull login in login page controller

try this

```
// Render the element in /homepage.ctp
   $this->render('homepage');
```